# avoid explicit cast at scala's dynamic types

Tags: scala

I add variables with `Dynamic` from scala 2.10.0-RC1 like this:

```
import language.dynamics
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

object Main extends Dynamic {
  private val map = new HashMap[String, Any]
  def selectDynamic(name: String): Any = {return map(name)}
  def updateDynamic(name:String)(value: Any) = {map(name) = value}
}

val fig = new Figure(...)  // has a method number

Main.figname = fig
```

Now, if I want to access `Main.figname.number` it doesn't work, because the compiler thinks it's of type `Any`.

But it's also `Main.figname.isInstanceOf[Figure] == true`, so it's `Any` and `Figure`, but doesn't have `Figures` abilities. Now I can cast it like, `Main.figname.asInstanceOf[Figure].number` and it works! This is ugly! And I can't present this to my domain users (I'd like to build a internal DSL.)

Note: If I use instead of `Any` the supertype of `Figure` it doesn't work either.

Is this a bug in scala 2.10, or a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite logical. You are explicitly returning instances of `Any`. A workaround would be to have instances of Dynamic all along:

```
import language.dynamics
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

trait DynamicBase extends Dynamic {
  def as[T:ClassTag]: T
  def selectDynamic[T](name: String): DynamicBase
  def updateDynamic(name:String)(value: Any)
}

class ReflectionDynamic( val self: Any ) extends DynamicBase with Proxy {
  def as[T:ClassTag]: T = { implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]].cast( self ) }
   // TODO: cache method lookup for faster access + handle NoSuchMethodError
  def selectDynamic[T](name: String): DynamicBase = {
    val ref = self.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
    val clazz = ref.getClass
    clazz.getMethod(name).invoke( ref ) match {
      case dyn: DynamicBase => dyn
      case res => new ReflectionDynamic( res )
    }
  }
  def updateDynamic( name: String )( value: Any ) = {
    val ref = self.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
    val clazz = ref.getClass
    // FIXME: check parameter type, and handle overloads
    clazz.getMethods.find(_.getName == name+"_=").foreach{ meth =>
      meth.invoke( ref, value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef] )
    }
  }
}

object Main extends DynamicBase {  
  def as[T:ClassTag]: T = { implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]].cast( this ) }
  private val map = new HashMap[String, DynamicBase]
  def selectDynamic[T](name: String): DynamicBase = { map(name) }
  def updateDynamic(name:String)(value: Any) = {
    val dyn = value match {
      case dyn: DynamicBase => dyn
      case _ => new ReflectionDynamic( value )
    }
    map(name) = dyn
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
scala>     class Figure {
     |       val bla: String = "BLA"
     |     }
defined class Figure
scala> val fig = new Figure()  // has a method number
fig: Figure = Figure@6d1fa2
scala> Main.figname = fig
Main.figname: DynamicBase = Figure@6d1fa2
scala> Main.figname.bla
res40: DynamicBase = BLA
```

All instances are wrapped in a Dynamic instance.
We can recover the actual type using the `as` method which performs a dynamic cast.

```
scala> val myString: String = Main.figname.bla.as[String]
myString: String = BLA
```

Comment: As a side note, I had to define `selectDynamic` as `def selectDynamic[T](name: String): DynamicBase` instead of just `def selectDynamic(name: String): DynamicBase`. The superfluous type parameter is here to make the compiler happy, otherwise it chokes on the call to `as` (saying that `selectDynamic` doe not take a type parameter, even though the call to `as`  is direct and does not go through `selectDynamic`. It appears to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any extensions or custom functionalities to `Any` or any predefined `value classes`. You can define an implicit value class like this:

```
  implicit class CustomAny(val self: Any) extends AnyVal {
    def as[T] = self.asInstanceOf[T]
  }
```

Usage:

```
scala> class Figure {
     | val xyz = "xyz"
     | }
defined class Figure
scala> val fig = new Figure()
fig: Figure = Figure@73dce0e6

scala> Main.figname = fig
Main.figname: Any = Figure@73dce0e6

scala> Main.figname.as[Figure].xyz
res8: String = xyz
```

The implicit value class is not costly like like regular class. It will be optimised in compile time and it will be equivalent to a method call on a static object, rather than a method call on a newly instantiated object.

You can find more info on implicit value class [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).

Comment: How is that better than directly using `asInstanceOf` as OP did (and explicitly qualified as "ugly")?